# Add more than 6 face contents to this beautiful Hexagon Text Roller

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Trying to use this beautiful Hexagon Text Roller I have faced a confusing issue.

[Here is the code in CodePen.](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/RwKaNEB?editors=1010)

And Here is the code:

```js
const carouselData = [
  { phrase: 'we have a phrase 1', translation: 'this is the translation'},
  { phrase: 'we have a phrase 2', translation: 'this is the translation'},
  { phrase: 'we have a phrase 3', translation: 'this is the translation'},
  { phrase: 'we have a phrase 4', translation: 'this is the translation'},
  { phrase: 'we have a phrase 5', translation: 'this is the translation'},
  { phrase: 'we have a phrase 6', translation: 'this is the translation'},
  
  //{ phrase: 'we have a phrase 7', translation: 'this is the translation'}, // this is 7th 
  //{ phrase: 'we have a phrase 8', translation: 'this is the translation'}, // this is 8th
  
];


renderCarousel();

var increment = 0;
var bdLen = 6;
var carousel = $('#carousel');

var _ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var TOUCHEVENT = {
  touchstart: "touchstart",
  touchmove: "touchmove",
  touchend: "touchend",
  isdesktop:_ua.indexOf('android')>-1 ||_ua.indexOf('linux')>-1 ||_ua.indexOf('mobile')>-1 ||_ua.indexOf('iphone')>-1 ||_ua.indexOf('ipad')>-1 ? false : true,
  initTouchEvents: function () {
      if (TOUCHEVENT.isdesktop) {
        this.touchstart = "mousedown";
        this.touchmove = "mousemove";
        this.touchend = "mouseup";
      }
  },

};




$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        if($(this).hasClass('btn-next')) {
            nextCarousel();
        } else {
            previousCarousel();
        }
        return false;
    });
  
  
  function nextCarousel() {
    increment++;
    var _state = (increment % bdLen) + 1;
        _state = (_state < 1) ? (_state  % bdLen + bdLen) : _state;
        updateCarouselState(increment, _state);
    
  }
  
  function previousCarousel() {
    increment--;
    var _state = (increment % bdLen) + 1;
        _state = (_state < 1) ? (_state  % bdLen + bdLen) : _state;
        updateCarouselState(increment, _state);
  }

    initTouchEventHandle();


})
/*document ready end----------*/

function updateCarouselState(_incrementId, _stateId) {
    var preAngle = -(360/bdLen).toFixed(1);
    carousel.css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotateX(' + _incrementId * preAngle + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotateX(' + _incrementId * preAngle + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotateX(' + _incrementId * preAngle + 'deg)',
  });
  carousel.attr('data-state', _stateId );
}


function initTouchEventHandle(){
  TOUCHEVENT.initTouchEvents();

  var carouselCover = document.getElementById('cover');
  carouselCover.addEventListener(TOUCHEVENT.touchstart, onTouchStartHandle, false);
  carouselCover.addEventListener(TOUCHEVENT.touchmove, onTouchMoveHandle, false);
  carouselCover.addEventListener(TOUCHEVENT.touchend, onTouchEndHandle,false);
   carouselCover.addEventListener("touchcancel", onTouchEndHandle, false);
}


function onTouchStartHandle(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  if(!TOUCHEVENT.startPos){TOUCHEVENT.startPos = {x: 0, y:0}};
  if(!TOUCHEVENT.movePos){TOUCHEVENT.movePos = {x: 0, y:0}};
  TOUCHEVENT.offsetY = 0;

  TOUCHEVENT.coverTouch = true;
  var touchobj = (e.changedTouches) ? e.changedTouches[0] : {};
  TOUCHEVENT.startPos.x = touchobj.clientX || e.pageX;
  TOUCHEVENT.startPos.y = touchobj.clientY || e.pageY; // clicked point
  
}

function onTouchMoveHandle(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  
   if(!TOUCHEVENT.coverTouch) return;
    var touchobj = (e.changedTouches) ? e.changedTouches[0] : {};
    TOUCHEVENT.movePos.x = touchobj.clientX || e.pageX;
    TOUCHEVENT.movePos.y = touchobj.clientY || e.pageY; // clicked point
    var _offsetY = Math.floor((TOUCHEVENT.movePos.y - TOUCHEVENT.startPos.y)/25);
    if(_offsetY != TOUCHEVENT.offsetY){
      var _tgBtnEles = (_offsetY < TOUCHEVENT.offsetY ) ? $('.btn-prev') : $('.btn-next');
      TOUCHEVENT.offsetY = _offsetY;
        _tgBtnEles.trigger('click');
    }

    
}

function onTouchEndHandle(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  TOUCHEVENT.coverTouch =false;

}

var _carouselCover = document.getElementById('cover');

document.ontouchmove= function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  // $('#fixed').html('touch move');
}




function renderCarousel() {
  let render = '';
  const carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    render += 
    `<figure>
      <h1>${carouselData[i].phrase}</h1>
      <h2>${carouselData[i].translation}</h2>
    </figure>
    `;
  }
  carousel.innerHTML = render;
}
```

```css
body { background: #333; }

#carousel-wrapper,
#carousel figure {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  
}

#carousel-wrapper .btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    line-height: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    background:gray;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
    transform:translate(-50%,0);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,0);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,0);
}

#carousel-wrapper .btn-next{
  bottom:-45px;
  top:auto;
}



#carousel figure:nth-of-type(1) {-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg)   translateZ(86px); transform: rotateX(0deg)   translateZ(86px);}
#carousel figure:nth-of-type(2) {-webkit-transform: rotateX(60deg)  translateZ(86px); transform: rotateX(60deg)  translateZ(86px);}
#carousel figure:nth-of-type(3) {-webkit-transform: rotateX(120deg) translateZ(86px); transform: rotateX(120deg) translateZ(86px);}
#carousel figure:nth-of-type(4) {-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(86px); transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(86px);}
#carousel figure:nth-of-type(5) {-webkit-transform: rotateX(240deg) translateZ(86px); transform: rotateX(240deg) translateZ(86px);}
#carousel figure:nth-of-type(6) {-webkit-transform: rotateX(300deg) translateZ(86px); transform: rotateX(300deg) translateZ(86px);}

#carousel[data-state="1"] figure:nth-of-type(1),
#carousel[data-state="2"] figure:nth-of-type(2),
#carousel[data-state="3"] figure:nth-of-type(3),
#carousel[data-state="4"] figure:nth-of-type(4),
#carousel[data-state="5"] figure:nth-of-type(5),
#carousel[data-state="6"] figure:nth-of-type(6) { opacity: 1;  background:rgba(180,180,180,1);}

#carousel-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 1100px;
  padding: 20% 0;
}

#carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /*z-index: 100;*/
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .6s;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#carousel figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background:rgba(180,180,180,.4);
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .4;

  transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  -moz-transition: all .6s;

  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#carousel-wrapper .cover{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  /*z-index: 100;*/
}

#fixed{
  position: absolute;
  left:auto;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
}


#carousel figure h1 {
  color: #ff0d4d;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;    
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#carousel figure h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;   
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <div id="carousel-wrapper">
    <div id="carousel" data-state="1" style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg)">
<!--       <figure>Side 1</figure>
      <figure>Side 2</figure>
      <figure>Side 3</figure>
      <figure>Side 4</figure>
      <figure>Side 5</figure>
      <figure>Side 6</figure> -->
    </div>
    <span class="cover" id = "cover"></span>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-prev">prev</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-next">next</a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

As you see at the very beginning of the code I have this variable `carouselData` holding data to render the hexagon's content.

The hexagon has 6 faces. and the Css of the code tries to control those 6 faces **But what if we want to render more than 6 contents inside these 6 faces?**

I mean we still have 6 face in the hexagon but as user touches (the code supports touch) or clicks the **next** or **prev** buttons he/she can see the 7th and 8th content after the 6th face.. after the 8th one he/she will see the first face again...

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things what need to be amended:

JS:

1. Change `var bdLen = 6;` to `var bdLen = carouselData.length;`
2. Change `for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {` to `for(let i = 0; i < carouselData.length; i++) {` inside `function renderCarousel()`

CSS:

1. Removed all rules for `#carousel figure:nth-of-type(x)`, they are now set in js
2. Left `#carousel[data-state="x"] figure:nth-of-type(x)` only for the first element, others will be updated from js

```js
const carouselData = [{
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 1',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  },
  {
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 2',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  },
  {
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 3',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  },
  {
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 4',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  },
  {
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 5',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  },
  {
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 6',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  },
  {
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 7',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  },
  {
    phrase: 'we have a phrase 8',
    translation: 'this is the translation'
  }
];


renderCarousel();

var increment = 0;
var bdLen = carouselData.length;
var carousel = $('#carousel');

var _ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var TOUCHEVENT = {
  touchstart: "touchstart",
  touchmove: "touchmove",
  touchend: "touchend",
  isdesktop: _ua.indexOf('android') > -1 || _ua.indexOf('linux') > -1 || _ua.indexOf('mobile') > -1 || _ua.indexOf('iphone') > -1 || _ua.indexOf('ipad') > -1 ? false : true,
  initTouchEvents: function() {
    if (TOUCHEVENT.isdesktop) {
      this.touchstart = "mousedown";
      this.touchmove = "mousemove";
      this.touchend = "mouseup";
    }
  },

};




$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-next')) {
      nextCarousel();
    } else {
      previousCarousel();
    }
    return false;
  });


  function nextCarousel() {
    increment++;
    var _state = (increment % bdLen) + 1;
    _state = (_state < 1) ? (_state % bdLen + bdLen) : _state;
    updateCarouselState(increment, _state);

  }

  function previousCarousel() {
    increment--;
    var _state = (increment % bdLen) + 1;
    _state = (_state < 1) ? (_state % bdLen + bdLen) : _state;
    updateCarouselState(increment, _state);
  }

  initTouchEventHandle();


})
/*document ready end----------*/

function updateCarouselState(_incrementId, _stateId) {
  var preAngle = -(360 / bdLen).toFixed(1);
  carousel.css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotateX(' + _incrementId * preAngle + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotateX(' + _incrementId * preAngle + 'deg)',
    'transform': 'rotateX(' + _incrementId * preAngle + 'deg)',
  });
  carousel.attr('data-state', _stateId);
  carousel.find('figure').css({
    opacity: .4,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(180, 180, 180, .4)'
  }).eq(_stateId - 1).css({
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(180, 180, 180)'
  })
}


function initTouchEventHandle() {
  TOUCHEVENT.initTouchEvents();

  var carouselCover = document.getElementById('cover');
  carouselCover.addEventListener(TOUCHEVENT.touchstart, onTouchStartHandle, false);
  carouselCover.addEventListener(TOUCHEVENT.touchmove, onTouchMoveHandle, false);
  carouselCover.addEventListener(TOUCHEVENT.touchend, onTouchEndHandle, false);
  carouselCover.addEventListener("touchcancel", onTouchEndHandle, false);
}


function onTouchStartHandle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  if (!TOUCHEVENT.startPos) {
    TOUCHEVENT.startPos = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  };
  if (!TOUCHEVENT.movePos) {
    TOUCHEVENT.movePos = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  };
  TOUCHEVENT.offsetY = 0;

  TOUCHEVENT.coverTouch = true;
  var touchobj = (e.changedTouches) ? e.changedTouches[0] : {};
  TOUCHEVENT.startPos.x = touchobj.clientX || e.pageX;
  TOUCHEVENT.startPos.y = touchobj.clientY || e.pageY; // clicked point

}

function onTouchMoveHandle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();

  if (!TOUCHEVENT.coverTouch) return;
  var touchobj = (e.changedTouches) ? e.changedTouches[0] : {};
  TOUCHEVENT.movePos.x = touchobj.clientX || e.pageX;
  TOUCHEVENT.movePos.y = touchobj.clientY || e.pageY; // clicked point
  var _offsetY = Math.floor((TOUCHEVENT.movePos.y - TOUCHEVENT.startPos.y) / 25);
  if (_offsetY != TOUCHEVENT.offsetY) {
    var _tgBtnEles = (_offsetY < TOUCHEVENT.offsetY) ? $('.btn-prev') : $('.btn-next');
    TOUCHEVENT.offsetY = _offsetY;
    _tgBtnEles.trigger('click');
  }


}

function onTouchEndHandle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  TOUCHEVENT.coverTouch = false;

}

var _carouselCover = document.getElementById('cover');

document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  // $('#fixed').html('touch move');
}




function renderCarousel() {
  let render = '';
  const carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
  const rotateXincrement = 360 / carouselData.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < carouselData.length; i++) {
    const rotateX = rotateXincrement * i;
    render +=
      `<figure style='transform: rotateX(${rotateX}deg) translateZ(100px);'>
      <h1>${carouselData[i].phrase}</h1>
      <h2>${carouselData[i].translation}</h2>
    </figure>
    `;
  }
  carousel.innerHTML = render;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

#carousel-wrapper,
#carousel figure {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#carousel-wrapper .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  line-height: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#carousel-wrapper .btn-next {
  bottom: -45px;
  top: auto;
}

#carousel[data-state="1"] figure:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 1);
}

#carousel-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 1100px;
  padding: 20% 0;
}

#carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /*z-index: 100;*/
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .6s;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#carousel figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(180, 180, 180, .4);
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .4;
  transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  -moz-transition: all .6s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#carousel-wrapper .cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /*z-index: 100;*/
}

#fixed {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
}

#carousel figure h1 {
  color: #ff0d4d;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#carousel figure h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div id="carousel-wrapper">
  <div id="carousel" data-state="1" style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg)">

  </div>
  <span class="cover" id="cover"></span>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-prev">prev</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-next">next</a>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, plus one, but this way I need to add the css via javascript

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by this. What css do you need to add via javascript? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know the exact number of content, I may have 6 or 8 or 10 contents and based on that I should change the css dynamically.. right?

Comment: Ah, ok, now it makes sense. I thought you will always have 8 elements. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: did you changed the code, it seems some glitches happen in the rotating graphic!!!

Comment: Take a look at the editeded version. No you can update the data and the code will reflect the data changes.

Comment: Mr T great job... but there is a glitch at the top and bottom of current face when it's moving! any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is it a glitch? The `opacity` is changing, hence you see a `fade` effect.

Comment: Please compare the original code pen with yours:

Comment: Original: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/RwKaNEB?editors=1010